# How To Display Google Map in android emulator?I tried this program in google AVD in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is my code to display the google map in my android emulator using google AVD....
How to fix this problem?anybody can know this?

Map.java:

```
    public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
    {    
        private MapView mapView;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);      
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            return false;
        }
```

Xml File:

```
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"
            >
            </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

Manifost File:

```
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Output:
        In my emulator map activity has stopped unexpexctly..
         i got the runtime exception

```
01-04 10:36:24.540: D/dalvikvm(641): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-04 10:36:25.290: W/dalvikvm(641): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/MapsActivity; (10)
01-04 10:36:25.290: W/dalvikvm(641): Link of class 'Lcom/example/MapsActivity;' failed
01-04 10:36:25.290: D/AndroidRuntime(641): Shutting down VM
01-04 10:36:25.290: W/dalvikvm(641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MapsActivity
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MapsActivity
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-04 10:36:25.430: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
01-04 10:36:31.140: W/dalvikvm(679): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/MapsActivity; (10)
01-04 10:36:31.160: W/dalvikvm(679): Link of class 'Lcom/example/MapsActivity;' failed
01-04 10:36:31.160: D/AndroidRuntime(679): Shutting down VM
01-04 10:36:31.180: W/dalvikvm(679): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MapsActivity
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MapsActivity
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-04 10:36:31.240: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  ... 11 more
01-04 10:37:23.619: W/dalvikvm(720): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/MapsActivity; (10)
01-04 10:37:23.659: W/dalvikvm(720): Link of class 'Lcom/example/MapsActivity;' failed
01-04 10:37:23.659: D/AndroidRuntime(720): Shutting down VM
01-04 10:37:23.669: W/dalvikvm(720): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MapsActivity
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MapsActivity
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-04 10:37:23.699: E/AndroidRuntime(720):  ... 11 more
```

Output screen:

```
             google map view screen shot
```

Comment: Have u created correct api key?

Comment: how to create api key?i just copy and paste the key in my android program

Comment: @yugandhar has already gave u the answer, follow that tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mentioned code  is right But i have two doubt is that

```
1. Google MAP API
```

`Ans .`To get Google MAP API [Here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/obtain-google-maps-api-key.html)

```
2. Check Emulator's Internet.
```

`Ans .` Open CMD 
D:\SOFTWARE\Android-SDK\android-sdk-2.2>emulator -avd avdname -dns-server 8.8.8.8

Comment: i am using ubuntu.how to check ?i got the key from google website .they provided this key before accept with MD% certificate 
 android:apiKey="0zHtW2OR2Qr20fb8lQU8SSZ4Z6gVl0mVZnC98aw"

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with your API key only. Any how check the link below you will get an idea.

[Displaying Google maps in Android Emulator](http://blogspot.fluidnewmedia.com/2009/04/displaying-google-maps-in-the-android-emulator/)

I found one thing in your manifest, you written

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

after `</application>` i think it may wrong

In manifest file write as below and try once

```
<application
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

**New Answer**

Please check this link, it may help you.
[Enable internet for Android Emulator](http://rashidnoorani.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-enable-access-internet-for.html)

Comment: My  android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"

Comment: now problem has been solved.but the images are not displayed like google map is not displayed

Comment: see  i couldnt post the screen shot.i have only 11 votes.i dont have that much restrcition in stackoverflow.any email id

Comment: i didt get any email.how to send.your profile dont have email id

Comment: @InfantRajesh check new answer

Answer (score 0):

add google maps library  in your manifest and it should work

Comment: 01-04 11:02:03.101: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 166K, 4% free 6797K/7047K, paused 4ms+4ms
01-04 11:02:03.111: W/CursorWrapperInner(658): Cursor finalized without prior close()
01-04 11:02:03.111: W/CursorWrapperInner(658): Cursor finalized without prior close()
01-04 11:02:03.261: I/MapActivity(658): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
01-04 11:02:03.261: E/MapActivity(658): Couldn't get connection factory client

Answer (score 0):

Move :

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

within the application tag. You have written outside the application tag in manifest file.

For your second problem: 
I am sure you have copied the map key from some where else. This is causing only blank screen on emulator. Try to generate your own Map Key following:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Answer (score 0):

the error class not found exception is  when actitvity is not declared in manifest
if you have declared it and then also error comes please please check you may have 
included a jar file twice in your project